# line numbering in article class

Tags: article, line-numbering

I want to make numbering line even though they are blank lines in the article class, how can I do with package of lineno?

You can wonder why I must numbering the blank line because that is requirement of a journal to which I will submit.

Here is the sample
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,times,10pt,authoryear]{article}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage[top=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{manyeqns}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off,labelsep=space, figurename=FIGURE,tablename=TABLE,textfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\bf}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lhead{Vo Duc Hoang Vu, N. Lethanh, Thi Thuy An Vo}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagewiselinenumbers
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
 ..........
 \end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `blank lines`? Can you give us an example of the output you want?

Comment: Technically, there are no blank lines.  Even the paragraph break is implemented as a \parskip sized \vspace (or \vskip, i forget which).

Comment: @JohnKormylo: neither `\vspace` nor `\vskip`; the `\parskip` glue is inserted automatically by the TeX core.  See, for example, the description of the `\indent` command at the bottom of page 282 of _The TeXbook_.

Comment: @touhami: this link leads to the image that i want to have latex code: https://flic.kr/p/wvwGqz

Comment: The thing is, they are not really blank lines. And they will often not be exactly a certain number of lines worth of height. So it isn't obvious how they should be numbered either. (if a vertical space is equivalent in height to 1.5 lines of text, is that one blank line or two?) You should first check whether the journal provides a class. Also, are you certain that you are meant to add the numbers? Journals I've submitted to have often numbered lines, but they have added them as part of the submission process - I've never needed to add them myself.

Comment: Also, please edit your question and include the image there. This gives your question persistent usefulness (the image won't disappear), and is just generally much easier for people to view. I saw your image for about 2s and then it disappeared leaving an entirely grey background. If the image was here, I would normally be able to see it inline. (And when I can't, I know how to workaround the problem.)

Comment: @cfr: I did edit the question with adding the picture so that other people can follow and help me. thanks

Comment: That's helpful - thanks. Have you checked if the journal provides a class or package? And whether you are really meant to add the numbers yourself?

Comment: @cfr: I also added latex code in the question. I use option of "\pagewiselinenumbers" to reset line number on each new page as requested by the journal. The figure above is sample of the journal I must follow. thanks

Comment: Which journal is it?